# Прямой http доступ к файлам изображений Laravel

Tags: laravel, изображения, файловая-система

Подскажите, пожалуйста как организовать http доступ к файлам в laravel.

Структура следующая:

- Картинки хранятся в папке `storage/app/images`
- К картинке должен быть по её полному URL (например: `http://domain.ru/image1.jpg`)

Примерно понимаю что в конфиге filesystem.php надо сделать так:

```
'disks' => [
...
        'images' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path('images'),
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
...
```

А что дальше делать, понятия не имею. Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Файлы, к которым должен быть публичный доступ, должны, как правило, храниться в директории `storage/app/public`.

Сформируйте ссылку при помощи команды CLI Artisan

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Размещайте в директории `storage\app\public\image` и они будут доступны через `http://domain.ru/storage/image/image1.jpg`.